# Aegir for Drupal 10

Tags: aegir

With Aegir being developed in Drupal 7 and the end of life looming for this November are there plans to migrate Aegir from Drupal 7 to 10?  Or can anyone direct me to where I can find the migrated version.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, Aegir 3, the current stable major version, is minimally-maintained. Vendors offering support are Omega8, Consensus, ThinkDrop, and Symbiotic (who maintains some components at github.com/coopsymbiotic). Find them all at https://docs.aegirproject.org/community/services/.

For on-going support (as Debian packages are no longer maintained):

- Install from Git, and follow the 7.x-3.x branches, or
- Use Consensus' Ansible roles (https://gitlab.com/consensus.enterprises/ansible-roles/)
- Migrate to the BOA fork (https://github.com/omega8cc/boa), which will continue as an Aegir 3 LTS initiative. Please see their issue queue (and create a migration ticket for this if there isn't one already).
- Migrate to OpenDevShop (https://github.com/opendevshop/devshop). DevShop will continue to develop & support the Hosting modules in the 4.x branch until everything can be ported to Drupal 9+.

Aegir 5 is a complete rewrite in development (https://gitlab.com/aegir/aegir/), but progress is slow due to insufficient funding. [Get in touch](https://consensus.enterprises/#contact) if you'd like to help with this initiative by providing funding, developer time, or anything else.  Please see [the blog posts on this topic](https://consensus.enterprises/tags/aegir5/).

Answer (score 0):

According to [today's update](https://consensus.enterprises/blog/aegir5-roadmap-update/), you must upgrade to Aegis 5:

> Along with the offers of support, we’ve also heard a variety of
> concerns about the future of the Aegir system or Aegir 5 in
> particular. For example:
>
> 1. Can Aegir 3 support Drupal 10?
> 2. Will there be a migration path from Aegir 3 to Aegir 5?
> 3. Does Aegir 5 support multi-site environments?
> 4. Can Aegir 5 satisfy a SaaS use-case?
>
> The first 2 of these we can answer directly:
>
> 1. No. Fundamental divergence between PHP8, D10, and Drush make this effectively impossible.
> 2. Yes! Onboarding Aegir 3 sites to Aegir 5 is a key use-case on our radar.
>
> Questions 3 and 4 warrant more detailed answers, which we plan to post
> about shortly, but the short answers are “sort of” and “most
> definitely” respectively. The Aegir 5 architecture in general is a lot
> more flexible, intended to enable use-case-specific pluggability.